# Values Not Being Read in Correctly From File

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-io

I am trying to read in x,y coordinates in from a file separated by a comma. However, the elements are not being added to the ArrayList properly. Where am I going wrong here?

```
ArrayList<Double> xpointArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> ypointArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
try {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        line = input.readLine();
        String[] splitLine = line.split(",");

        double xValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[0]);
        double yValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]);

        xpointArrayList.add(xValue);
        ypointArrayList.add(yValue);
    }
    input.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

    }

    double[] xpoints = new double[xpointArrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++) {
        xpoints[i] = xpointArrayList.get(i);
    }
    double[] ypoints = new double[ypointArrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ypoints.length; i++) {
        ypoints[i] = ypointArrayList.get(i);
    }
```

When I do the Array.toSring call on the xpoints and the ypoints array. It only has one number. For example in the file:

```
1,2
3,4
0,5
```

It only has 3.0 for the xpoints array and 4.0 for the ypoints array. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: "1,2 / 3,4 / 0,5" what does it mean ?

Comment: You should not ignore the exception.

Comment: The slash meant newline. 1,2 is on one line, 3,4 is the next line, 0,5 is the next line. Brian Roach solved it though.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung For the purpose of this program, I just ignored it so the compiler would not complain. I would normally not do that, but for this I do not care about it. (I am assuming good input.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    line = input.readLine();
```

You just read a line, discarded it, then read another line.

Rinse, repeat (since it's a loop).

In the future, you really should think about using the debugger. You can step through your code as it executes and see exactly what is going on. Learning to use it will be *invaluable*.

**Edit To add:** As GregHaskins points out the comments below, you also obscured the problem by catching the `NullPointerException` and not acting on it. On the second iteration of your loop, `line` would be `null` on the second call to `readLine()` because there was nothing left in the file. The call to `split()` then throws a `NullPointerException` which you catch ... then silently ignore.

Comment: I might add that catching the `NullPointerException` also probably further obscured the issue at hand---you'd get that NPE at the beginning of the second iteration of the given dataset since it would be trying to read the *fourth* line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read input using the Scanner class. The following is a modified version of your code using the Scanner and File classes to read the File:

```
ArrayList<Double> xpointArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> ypointArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("testing.txt"));
    String line;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        line = input.nextLine();
        String[] splitLine = line.split(",");

        double xValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[0]);
        double yValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]);

        xpointArrayList.add(xValue);
        ypointArrayList.add(yValue);
    }
    input.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

    }

    double[] xpoints = new double[xpointArrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++) {
        xpoints[i] = xpointArrayList.get(i);
    }
    double[] ypoints = new double[ypointArrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ypoints.length; i++) {
        ypoints[i] = ypointArrayList.get(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reading style is not right. You are calling the readLine() two times. One at the top and other just after entering the while() loop. This way u are not processing all the points. Some point coordinates are getting ignored.
You should use.

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

//line = input.readLine(); */Remove this */

*/your code */

}
```